# On Linux - set maximum open files to unlimited. Possible?

Tags: linux, kernel, redhat

Is it possible to set the maximum number of open files to some "infinite" value or must it be a number?

I had a requirement to set the descriptor limit for a daemon user to be "unlimited" and I'm trying to determine if that's possible or how to do it. I've seen some mailing lists refer to a "max" value that can be used (as in: "myuser hard nofile max", but so far the man pages and references I've consulted don't back that up.

If I can't use 'max' or similar, I'd like to know how to determine what the max number of files is (theoretically) so I have some basis for whatever number I pick. I don't want to use 100000000 or something if there's a more reasonable way to get an upper bound.

I'm using RHEL 5 if it's important.

**Update:** I'm an idiot when it comes to writing questions. Ideally I'd like to do this in the limits.conf file (which is where "max" would come from). Does that change any answers?

---

Thanks for the comments. This is for a JBOSS instance and not a daemon I'm writing so I don't know if setrlimit() is useful to me. However, Jefromi - I do like the definition of Infinity :) I saw a post that suggests a file descriptor is "two shorts and a pointer" so I should be able to calculate the approximate upper bound.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

POSIX allows you to set the `RLIMIT_NOFILE` resource limit to `RLIM_INFINITY` using [`setrlimit()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html).  What this means is that the system will not enforce this resource limit.  Of course, you will still be limited by the implementation (e.g. `MAXINT`) and any other resource limitations (e.g. available memory).

**Update:** RHEL 5 has a maximum value of 1048576 (2<sup>20</sup>) for this limit (`NR_OPEN` in `/usr/include/linux/fs.h`), and will not accept any larger value including infinity, even for root.  So on RHEL 5 you can use this value in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and that is as close as you are going to get to infinity.

Not long ago [a Linux kernel patch](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=0c2d64fb6cae9aae480f6a46cfe79f8d7d48b59f) was applied to allow this limit to be set to infinity, however [it has since been reverted as a result of unintended consequences](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=60fd760fb9ff7034360bab7137c917c0330628c2).

Comment: Has anything changed recently as of 2015?

Comment: Potentially useful: Ubuntu 14.04 also has this 2^20 limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Anything past that will reset the limit to the default 2^10

Comment: [You can get beyond 2^20 by setting fs.nr_open](https://superuser.com/a/1468838/961803), at least in Centos 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try the line

```
<domain>    -
```

replacing `<domain>` with the username, in the simplest case.

The [limits.conf man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html) says

> ```
> -
>     for enforcing both soft and hard resource limits together.
>
>     Note, if you specify a type of '-' but neglect to supply the
>     item and value fields then the module will never enforce any
>     limits on the specified user/group etc. .
> ```