# Findbugs UnionBugs throws Exception "Trouble reading/parsing" as part of maven build and works from command line

Tags: maven, ant, findbugs

Has anyone seen problems with UnionBugs ant task?

My maven build generates findbugs via maven plugin and concatenates xml via antrun using unionBugs in a reporting project that concatenates all the reports together via antrun.   When the end to end build runs I see the error below but the files exist and can be read.  When I just run the concat project after the build I generate the desired report.   I'd expect heap space issues to throw a very different error and have 2G for heap.

Let me know if you have some ideas how to investigate this.  If not, I'll update the question should I figure it out.  For now, I'm splitting this into two maven executions which is ok but not ideal.

**error**

```
Trouble reading/parsing .../core/api/target/findbugs/findbugsXml.xml
```

**pom excerpt**

```
<taskdef name="unionBugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.UnionBugs" classpathref="maven                <taskdef name="unionBugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.UnionBugs" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

            <!-- Combin findbugs output -->
            <delete dir="${trunk}/target/findbugs" />
            <mkdir dir="${trunk}/target/findbugs" />
            <unionBugs to="${findbugs.xml.out}">
              <fileset dir="${trunk}">
                <include name="core/**/target/findbugs/findbugsXml.xml"/>
                <include name="app/target/findbugs/findbugsXml.xml"/>
                <include name="modules/*/target/findbugs/findbugsXml.xml"/>
              </fileset>
            </unionBugs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be caused my exceeding ulimit for max open files (ulimit -n).  I do not know if this is the only way to encounter the problem.

- Problem happens only after running a full build which generates findbugs results
- unionBugs task executed in separate maven process does not cause the problem
- ulimit -n175 ; cd concat-findbugs; mvn install   *results in the problem*

Solution - raise the ulimit [Setting Max Open files on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212925/on-linux-set-maximum-open-files-to-unlimited-possible)