# Listening on multiple ports

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm playing a bit with Twisted and created a simple 'server'.
I'd like to let the server listening on multiple ports (1025-65535) instead of a single port.
How can i do this ?

My code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,ServerFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class QuickDisconnectProtocol(Protocol): 
    def connectionMade(self): 
        print "Connection from : ", self.transport.getPeer()
        self.transport.loseConnection() # terminate connection


f = ServerFactory()
f.protocol = QuickDisconnectProtocol
reactor.listenTCP(6666,f)
reactor.run()
```

Already tried this:

```
for i in range (0, 64510):
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i,f)

reactor.run()
```

But received an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 436, in listenTCP
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 641, in startListening
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:2044: [Errno 24] Too many open files.
```

Comment: Add more listeners before you call `reactor.run()` for each port you wish to listen to...

Comment: I tried a for loop (for i in range(0, 64510) and 1025+i, but an error occurred -  to many files open

Comment: Well yeah... why would a process need that many open ports? That's just ridiculous...

Comment: Just to respond on a port a client choose. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: That's not how these things work... if the client wants to connect to something they connect to a specific port (or a small range of ports)... it does so... Then, if need be they can negotiate other transport if they need to, but best not to go there with a manual protocol... Just use a single port, or a couple of ports if you need to...

Comment: Will adding more listening ports increases received throughput than when listening on 1 port only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each listening port requires a file descriptor ("open file"), and each file descriptor takes up one element of your maximum file descriptors quota.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212925/on-linux-set-maximum-open-files-to-unlimited-possible) has an answer explaining how to raise this limit on Linux, and [this blog post](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/) has resources as to how to do it on OS X.

That said, the other respondents who have told you that this is not a particularly sane thing to do are right.  In particular, your operating system may stop working if you actually go all the way up to 65535, this overrules the entire [ephemeral port range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), which means you may not be able to make TCP client connections from this machine any more.  So it would be good to explain in your question *why* you are trying to do this.

Comment: Just for testing purposes. That's why it's immediately disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to have one listening port ( chosen by the server! ).  If you want each client on its own port, then the server chooses the port, starts listening on it, and replies to the client with the port it will use for further requests.

It is not a real good use of port resources!  If the server needs to keep state information for each client then it should issue a unique ID to each client when the client first connects and the client should use this ID for every request to the server.

However, with a little care, you can often design the system so that the server does not need to keep separate state information for each client.

Comment: The server shouldn't need to issue a unique ID - the tuple `(serverIP, serverPort, clientIP, clientPort)` is sufficient and unique to the connection.

Comment: @twalberg  True.  However writing code for the server to gather this data and do a lookup on it in a state map is non trivial for every client request.  A single index into a a state vector is so much simpler.