# What is the way to find file descriptor ulimit in Linux

Tags: linux, ulimit

I have a few servers wherein the ulimit is set as 65536 while in some 200000.Not sure depending on what parameter it is taken, referred the question given on 
[[On Linux - set maximum open files to unlimited. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212925/on-linux-set-maximum-open-files-to-unlimited-possible][1])

But still not clear, what decides the max limit of File descriptors that we can set? Does it depend on memory? OS version or can it be anything. Or can I put any random number above 1024?

Comment: And because we can edit /proc/sys/file-max as well so no way I can find what is the max file descriptors limit that I can set and system can support without any crash

Answer (score 0):

According to the **proc**(5) manpage, the fs.file-max sysctl applies to the number of open files for all processes. Privileged processes (CAP_SYS_ADMIN) can override the file-max limit, though.

To set the per-process limit you must run **setrlimit**(2) with RLIMIT_NOFILE.  Be aware of the differences between the soft limit and the hard limit.

Comment: my question is what exactly can be the limit which i can set and on what parameters it depends on? As I can interpret you mean to say running the setrlimit command will get me the max number, is it? because I found no such command

Comment: setrlimit() is a syscall. The command (builtin from the shell) is ulimit. To view the soft limits: `ulimit -a`. To view the hard limit: `ulimit -Ha`. You may raise the soft limits to the hard limits. Only the superuser can raise its hard limits. To set the limits for the user you have to edit /etc/security/limits.conf. Look for "VFS: file-max limit <number> reached" error messages in syslog if the limits are too small.

The initial values depend on the amount on available memory.  Run `help ulimit` to see the flags used to set each limit.